# Which button is pressed in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list, button

I got these pieces of codes:

In cs:

A class of get and set of `ImgSmall`, `Name`, `ImgLarge`:

```
List<Img> sectionList = new List<Img> 
{ 
  new Img
  {
      ImgSmall="Img/NG.png", Name="New Game", ImgLarge="Img/NG.png"
  },

  new Img
  {
      ImgSmall="Img/HS.png", Name="High Score", ImgLarge="Img/HS.png"
  },
}
```

In XAML (A style template applying to `Images/Buttons`):

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Click="Button_Click_1" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Image x:Name="image" Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding ImgSmall}" />
</Button>
```

How do I check which `Button` is pressed when I create more than `1 Button`? My guess is to check the name of the passed object but I don't really got a clue.

The click method:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Your code only has a single button. Could you provide more code which actually demonstrates what your question is.

Comment: Well, I just added one more line for one more button =P. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think, the most important information was "(A style template applying to images/buttons)".

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out later. But Cedric came up with a perfect solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a very useful in this case: the property `Tag`. You set the `Tag` in XAML with a binding, then check its value.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if(sender != null)
    {
        Img tag = frameworkElement.Tag as Img;

        // You directly have the Img that correspond to the button you have clicked
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Click="Button_Click_1" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" >
    <Image x:Name="image" Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding ImgSmall}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution! So the passed object does not automatically contain the name variable of the Image? Interesting...
Thanks man!

Comment: Yes, this way, _Tag_ is a reference to the _Img_ object the button is associated with. If it works and solves your problem, don't forget to accept ;)